# Double Integration, Fubini's Theorem. Joint Continuity

Tags: integration, continuity

Could someone please help to show why this function is jointly discontinuous at (0,0). A step-by-step method would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[(2xy/(x^2 + y^2)]

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates $(x,y)=(r\cos t,r\sin t)$ your function is
$$\frac{2r^2\cos t\sin t}{r^2}=\sin 2t.$$
So if your point approaches $(0,0)$ on a straight line, the value it
takes depends on the angle of that line.

Comment: $2 \cos t \sin t$ is $\sin 2t$, not $\cos 2t$.